# Not able to open the recently pushed folder in git

Tags: git, github

Actually,I had a project and it was not linked with github before.So,to push into github i made new repository in github named as **"AnSpring"** and cloned it into my harddrive.

```
git clone HTTPS:
```

Then i copied the project folder and pasted into the **AnSpring** folder which was in my local drive:

[image]

I runned the command as:

[image]

But the folder **full-stack-with-angular-and-spring-boot** have multiple files inside but it is not being opened in github as :

[image]

the folder is appearing as unclickable in github.How can i add all the files inside of the folder **full-stack-with-angular-and-spring-boot** and open in github  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are putting a folder which already has a `.git` initialized inside it, into another newly cloned folder. Try to do it from the first.

1. Create a repository in your Github.
2. Clone that repository in your local machine with `git clone <repository-link>`
3. Copy the folder (only project files and folders with no `.git` file in it) into the newly cloned directory.
4. Do `git add -A` (or) `git add .` and then `git commit -m <message>`
5. Now push the changes using `git push origin master`

This should work because it is the appropriate steps to push your project from local to remote repository.

For reference : [Refer this link](https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line)

Sorry if it isn't working in your case.

Answer (score 0):

When you are clone git, it will automatically create a new folder. So in your case, you create a new folder and run `git init` command that creates .git file in your directory. Then you have cloned from git which eventually creates a new folder which has happened in your scenario.

You don't need to create a new folder for it. Just run git init in your existing project then add `git remote add origin HTTPS/SSH` finally push your code `git push -u origin master`(Assuming you have no other branch). Remember You are pushing existing folder not a new folder